# Can "rsync --append" replace files that are larger at destination?

Tags: bash, rsync

I have an rsync job that moves log files from a web server to an archive. The server rotates its own logs, so I might see a structure like this:

```
/logs
error.log
error.log.20200420
error.log.20200419
error.log.20200418
```

I use rsync to sync these log files every few minutes:

```
rsync --append --size-only /foo/logs/* /mnt/logs/
```

This command syncs everything with the least amount of processing. And it's important - calculating checksums or writing an entire file every time a few lines are added is a no-go. But it ignores files if there is a larger version on the server instead of replacing them:

> `man rsync`:
>
> `--append` [...] If a file needs to be transferred and its size on the receiver is the
>   same or longer than the size on the sender, the file is skipped.

Is there a way to tell rsync to replace files instead in this case? Using `--append` is important for me and works well for other log files that use unique filenames. Maybe there's a better tool for this?

The service is a packaged application that I can't really edit or configure unfortunately, so changing the file structure or paths isn't an option for me.

Comment: Don't use `--append`?

Comment: The question is if I can use `--append` *and* handle this case differently.